# Is the Champions of the Copper Cask event rigged?

Tags: fiz

So I just submitted a 850 quality brew to this tournament and I still came in second (previously in another game I tried a 650 and came in second as well).  That stupid Blahblaruuuuublarg (whatever) guy always won.  Is this supposed to be rigged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe so. I think as long as your beer is at a certain quality level, you'll come in second, otherwise you just lose. There's an event a little while later where you get another shot at the facility though, so don't worry! Start saving up some coin though

Comment: yea, I got the other event finally, seems like it is a rigged contest, too bad.

Comment: I can say for sure its rigged now, I still came in second after brewing a 10k+ quality beer